# \377\376 Appended to file (Windows -> Unix)

Tags: character-encoding, ssis, solaris, dos2unix

I have an [SSIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) package that performs the following.

1. Run a SQL script
2. Export the results to a flat file ([UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded, `;` delimited, and `\n` for new lines)
3. FTP results to a [Solaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29) machine (binary format)

The problem is that when the file shows up on my Solaris box, it has the following at the start of the file.

> \377\376

I have tried [dos2unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos), and it still has not corrected the issue. In fact, it changes the \377\376 to \227\226, not very helpful.

Is there a way to remove these characters from my file? When they are there, they mess with [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) and other Unix tools, like [head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(Unix)).

Comment: Thats a utf-16-le BOM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) so poke about in the export options to see if its possible to omit the BOM or use a bom aware viewer on solaris?

Comment: That's a Unicode byte-order mark. Looks like your output is not UTF-8 after all.

Comment: Thanks, I know where to start looking now. I am going to see if changing the output encoding to US-ASCII helps ( i know there are no special chars in my input ).

Comment: This is a candidate for a canonical question (for problems with BOMs. Or perhaps only for problems with BOMs UTF-16LE BOMs). There is also *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/)*, but perhaps it should be reserved for Unicode or [Windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) characters in the main part of the file.

Comment: Re *"I have tried dos2unix, and it still has not corrected the issue."*: What parameters did you use for dos2unix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, any SSIS or Windows-encoded file is UCS-2-LITTLE-ENDIAN encoded. The easiest way is to encode the file on your Unix server with the following commands.

1. Switch over to UTF-8 (or whatever encoding you need) with [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv):

   ```
   iconv -f UCS-2-LITTLE-EDIAN -t UTF-8 input > output
   ```
2. Remove the carriage returns that Microsoft adds to the end of lines.

   ```
   unix2dos -ascii utf-8-file outputfile
   ```

Comment: The two command lines do not seem to correspond (whether literal or not). Shouldn't `output` be `utf-8-file`?

Answer (score 0):

[Dos2unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) version 6.0 and higher can convert Windows Unicode UTF-16 files to Unix UTF-8. It will also remove the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM). Get the [latest dos2unix here](http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html).

There is a Windows version available.

Comment: That was already mentioned in the question, revision 1: "***I have tried dos2unix***, *and it still has not corrected the issue"*. Though the exact parameters were not revealed.

Answer (score 0):

As the previews answers stated, using [dos2unix](https://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html#DOS2UNIX) made the job. In my case I used:

```
dos2unix.exe -r -v -f -D utf8 <FileName>
```

in which:

> -r, --remove-bom      remove Byte Order Mark (default)
>
> -v,  --verbose        verbose operation
>
> -f, --force           force conversion of binary files
>
> -D, --display-enc     set encoding of displayed text messages encoding            ansi, unicode, utf8, default to ansi

And the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character was removed.