# Xcode \377 with an upside down '?'

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode

I'm programming with C++ in Xcode and I am trying to print out an array, but all that it prints is "\377" and an upside down '?' at the end of it. What does this mean?

Comment: BTW, octal 377 == 0xFF == 255.  Do you have valid characters in your array?  Are you in UTF-8 or UTF-16?

Comment: OK, this is about ***program output***, [not compiler errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462340/377-376-appended-to-file-windows-unix) (that would be something like *"xxxx.cpp:1: error: stray ‘\377’ in program"*). I retract my close vote.

Answer (score 1):

You probably generated whatever file you're reading on Windows in UTF-16. You should read and write your files in UTF-8. See [\377\376 Appended to file (Windows -> Unix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462340/377-376-appended-to-file-windows-unix) for more details on this pretty common problem.

If you need to read files in UTF-16 in C++, see [std::codecvt](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/codecvt/). That will help you get it over to UTF-8, which is what most of the Mac libraries expect.